# Looking for latest i386 DVD ISO download

Tags: centos, iso, download, x86, dvd

I'm having trouble finding this CentOS download:

- 7.6.1810
- *.ISO
- DVD
- i386

Does anyone know whether this particular build was made available?

Answer (score 1):

i386, *i.e.* 32-bit x86, builds of CentOS are available as [“alternative architecture” builds](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch) (“altarch” builds); see [here](http://isoredirect.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/) for the installation images.

The “Everything” image contains all of CentOS, and will fit on a dual-layer DVD. The “Minimal” image contains all the packages needed for a minimal installation of CentOS. See [the README](http://centos-altarch.reloumirrors.net/7.6.1810/isos/i386/0_README.txt) for details. There doesn’t seem to be an altarch equivalent to the “DVD” images of CentOS.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [this link describes what a CentOS "AltArch build" is.](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch)

Comment: Got it, thanks. I went through all of those; the DVD build isn't there. Everything, Minimal and NetInstall are the only ones available.

Comment: The "Everything" build will fit on a *dual-layer* DVD.

Comment: @telcoM ~ I'm trying for the DVD build because I came across a reference to the Gnome desktop being bundled there (I need a GUI so I can browse to a managed switch for configuration tasks). A bundled desktop isn't critical, but I'm trying to avoid downloading it as a separate package later. The Everything build is too large for me; I'm on sharply curtailed bandwidth.

Comment: @telcoM ~ Am I correct in my understanding that i386 is the 32-bit build?

Comment: Yes. You will often see `i386` as a generic architecture ID for "32-bit x86 processor", but sometimes (e.g. with RHEL 6.x and older) you might see `i686` or `i586` instead, to more accurately specify the minimum CPU feature set required.

Comment: @telcoM ~ Got it, thanks. (p.s. I didn't see your answer until just now, as it wasn't @ directed to me. If it's any consolation, I forget 'em all the time.)